# Why is world light bleeding in EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, world

I have a pipe with an opening, no lights in the scene. Only world light. And it's bleeding inside the pipe (even if I cover it with a plane). Why?? Shouldn't it be black due to lack of lighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the way global illumination must be "faked" in eevee, environment lighting is not obscured by objects (neither are reflections). The solution is to separate world background (if you plan to use it) from it's lighting influence, and provide the majority of your lighting with direct light sources - don't forget to enable contact shadows for the direct lights.

[image: Lights]

Comment: Damn... thank you.